# Ensure Pi Connects Only to Trusted WiFi Network Via Certificate

Tags: wifi, security

This bleeds into Information Security Exchange, however I am posting it here:

Suppose I am extremely paranoid and want to ensure my Pis only connect to WiFi access points with a certificate signed by my own home brewed CA (i.e. I created my own root CA certificate, and then signed a certificate with that).

How would I do this? How do I tell the Pi "connect to this SSID, and if the cert isn't signed by this CA, abort"?

Comment: @Ephemeral Clarified.

Comment: If you set up your WPA client for this, it will do it for you ... sorry I thought at first that you wanted to also create a secure access point.

Comment: [wpa_supplicant.conf](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf) and search with `tls` keyword and `ca_cert`.